# I need to know the number of days that two date ranges have in common with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know the number of days crossing that two date ranges have in common in mssql

How can write it ? Could you give me any samples ?

```
(FirstDay - SecondDay)  1. date range

(ThirdDay, FourthDay)   2.date range

SELECT 
    DAY_RANGE, 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, FirstDay, ThirdDay), 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, SecondDay, FourthDay)
FROM 
    Test
```

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results to your query.

Comment: Hello Gordon I haven't written it yet. I need some ideas.

Comment: Thank you Capricorn. I looking your link immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I would do the following:

```
1) Find out which of both start dates is greater
2) Find out which of both end dates is smaller
3) Calculate the number of dates between (1) and (2)
```

See SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/32006

**UPDATE:** as commented by @CetinBasoz, a negative return value need to be handled if there is no overlap.

Comment: What if there is no overlap? It returns minus values, no?

Comment: Thanks for the hint @CetinBasoz, I updated my answer.

Comment: It was already answered:)

Answer (score 0):

Murat, 
You can check the overlapping date range like this:

```
select case 
       when FirstDay < ThirdDay then ThirdDay
       else FirstDay end as rangeStart,
       case 
       when SecondDay > FourthDay then FourthDay
       else SecondDay end as rangeEnd,
       FirstDay, SecondDay, ThirdDay, FourthDay
from myTable
where FirstDay < FourthDay and SecondDay > ThirdDay;
```

You may prefer <= , >= instead of < and > depending on your range inclusivity.

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1eb149a5ca9457b426ceb115093fc252)